# How to create web-service in Moodle and using it with Android client

Tags: android, web-services, rest, soap, moodle

I dont know whether this question has been previously asked or not but before asking here, I searched through SO and also googled a lot, but did not get any proper solution.
I am working on an Android project, which uses Moodle (2.0) REST web-service. 
At my localhost server, I made a test run and getting output for '`moodle_user_get_users_by_id`' both for SOAP and REST protocols.
Then I searched for third-party libraries which can simplify my Web-service call headache and luckily I found [MoodleREST](https://sourceforge.net/projects/moodlerestjava/files/)

And [pattrickpollet GitHub](https://github.com/patrickpollet/moodlews_ksoap2)

But None is working as it should be.
If anyone have came across these problems earlier and know something about it, then it would be great if they can share it here..

Comment: No buddy. I'm not anymore working on it. Sorry :(